# EditText vs TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I read the API's and see that `TextView` is a super class to `EditText`, but I have a short and simple question: Generally speaking, `EditText` is used when the text displayed is subject to change, whether it's from the user or the app. `TextView` is used when the text displayed is to be constant/same forever. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Often you will even leave EditText blank with just a hint, and let the user fill out the entire text.

Comment: I use a TextView when the text is subject to change. EditView if expecting user input. Of interest, everything is a view so sometimes I use a TextView with an onClick event as a button when the needs warrant (small buttons that need to look consistent across versions, simulating a combo or toggle button). I just apply the same gradient that I use on my buttons and they look the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have done any java projects before, I see `Textview` and `EditText` are just same as `JLabel` and `JtextField` . If you want to ask user to enter username you will set an TextView with ("username " text in that, like you would do the same for JLabel). And then you make a textbox appear for user to enter the username that textbox is `EditText`. EditText is where user give their inputs for the program.

User cannot change something in TextView but program can(After user input correct user name you can set text for another TextView by the program saying that "Details correct" if you want that you have to write it in your program code. User can't make it appear). User can input any user name, But "username" textfield or `TextView` will remain unchange as "username" just like in a normal login interface.

Answer (score 16):

EditText is used for user input.

TextView is used to display text and is not editable by the user.  TextView can be updated programatically at any time.

Answer (score 3):

The names of them are pretty self explanatory. TextView is the widget used when you want the user to View  the Text (such as a label, etc) and EditText used when you want the user to be able to edit the text.  The text in either widget can be set programmatically or via xml using the `android:text` parameter.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) pretty much sums it up:

`EditText is a thin veneer over TextView that configures itself to be editable.`

Answer (score 2):

EditText is used when you expect an input from the user. EditText provides the behavior for user input (display keyboard, paste, position indicator, etc).

If your app is changing the content to display, you can just reset the text for the TextView. The user however cannot mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

**EditText** is Input Type/Field for inputting text

**TextView** is TextField for showing text

Comment: Not correct, from TextView Documentation: _Displays text to the user and optionally allows them to edit it._

[link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 0):

TextView is just like Label tag of HTML  on the other hand Edittext is input type.

Simple telling TextView is can't changable by the user. User only enter value.

Comment: that's a bad comparison - an HTML label is much more - it always belongs to a form element (if you click on a label, the linked element is focused)...