# Use android:EditText as label

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to set some text in EditText type fields. I want to do this while loading the activity. And then I don't want user to make any changes to it. Can I set EditText type boxes to non-editable mode? Does there exists any other element which could solve my purpose?

Comment: add android:editable="false" in EditText in xml or in java like yourEditText.seteditable(false);

Comment: @Shahzeb Thanks. However it doesn't work. I added android:editable = "false" in xml.  but I can still edit the text field.

Comment: you can call setEnabled(false); ...this method will disable the edittext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TextView` sounds like what you want; you can call `setText()` on them.

For EditText itself you could call [this version of setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType)), and set the buffer type to `NORMAL` instead of `EDITABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

there are two options. 
setEditable and setEnable. set false in Oncreate. 
but in setEditable user can edit text by long click -> paste option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not taking any input from user in the EditText and it is just used to show some text that is set programmatically at onCreate, then you can use [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) instead. It is more suited for your requirement.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531599/edittext-vs-textview) is a comparison between EditText and TextView that might be helpful.

Is there any particular reason for you to use a non-editable EditText? In case you absolutely have to use EditText then setting it as non-editable in your code after you set the value will suffice. You can do it in a few different ways, one of them would be setting input type as null in code.

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks @Swagata Acharyya

Answer (score 0):

You can do  android:enabled="false" in layout of that activity.
or
    editText.setEnabled(false);